# IntelliJIdea show me errors on the views of a Play project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, ide

I've recently ported a Play 2.3.2 application written in Scala from Eclipse to IntelliJIdea 13.1 Ultimate Edition.

For do that I import the project using SBT.

All works fine, but IntelliJ show me errors on some of my views package files.

In IntellijIDEA i get error like cannot resolve symbol `Assets`.

[image: Example of IntellijIdea errors]

I've installed correctly the Scala and Play plugins and the SBT works good.

What's wrong??

When in the Controllers I used the Play classes, all goes fine.

Comment: I might be late to the party, but is this issue still persisting?

Comment: Yes for me, but I'm using the community edition.

Comment: Alright, let me write the solution I have found for you :) Just quick question, code compiles fine right? It is just the issue of editor?